# Intersection of sphere and ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, partial-derivative, plane-curves

Ellipsoid:
$$
x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{2}=1
$$
Sphere:
$$
x^2+(y-1)^2+(z-d)^2=1
$$
For what values of $d$, there is a common tangent plane to both curves?

Part of my resolution:

Consider $f(x,y,z)=x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{2}\qquad$ and $g(x,y,z)=x^2+(y-1)^2+(z-d)^2$.

Then,

$f(x,y,z)=1$ and $g(x,y,z)=1$ are both level sets and a tangent plane (common) to them is given by, respectively:
$$
\overrightarrow \bigtriangledown f(P_0) \cdot PP_0=0
$$
$$
\overrightarrow \bigtriangledown g(P_1) \cdot PP_1=0
$$
with $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ points of tangency.

I obtained the planes:
$$
2x_0x+\frac{y_0}{2} y+z_0z=2
$$
$$
x_1x+(y_1-1)y+(z_1-d)z=y_1+d(z_1-d)
$$
Now, for a certain $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, we have:
$$
x_1 = 2 \lambda x_0
$$
$$
y_1-1 = \lambda \frac{y_0}{2}
$$
$$
z_1-d = \lambda z_0
$$
$$
y_1+d(z_1-d)=2 \lambda
$$

I tried to solve this system but there are to many variables...

Answer (score 1):

If $d\neq0$, we can easily see that the point $(0,2,d)$ on the sphere, in the plane of the biggest elliptical equator of the ellipsoid, is outside the ellipsoid. If $d=0$, then $(1/\surd2,\,1+1/\surd2,\,0)$ is clearly outside the ellipsoid. Hence, for all values of $d$, there is a point on the sphere outside the ellipsoid. The ellipsoid is too big to fit in the sphere; so some point of it must be outside the sphere. Hence there will always be parts of each surface outside the other surface, and so there will be a tangent plane common to them, whatever the value of $d$.

Comment: This common tangent plane will typically not touch each surface at the same point. An illusion I had when first thinking of the problem made me look for that to occur. [Of course a related problem is for what $d$ there can be a tangent plane to both surfaces going through a common point of the two surfaces...] And +1.

Comment: @coffeemath: For $d=0$, the surfaces have (among many others) the common tangent plane $y=2$. In this case, there is a common point of tangency: $(0,2,0)$. I would expect there to be no such common tangency points when $d\neq0$, but have no proof of this at present.

Comment: For $d>0$ I thought of starting with a sphere radius 1 centered at $(0,1,d)$ with a large enough $d>0$ that the sphere is completely outside the ellipsoid, then decreasing $d$ (moving the sphere downward) until it first touches the ellipsoid. [It may be such a movement winds up never meeting the ellipsoid, didn't check that.] If there is such a first touching value for $d$ it would give a solution. And then $-d$ would be another solution,

Comment: @coffeemath: You're right: That does give us another two points. And that's probably it now (3 points altogether).